# PHPMailer Sending Body As Text Attachment

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, goldmine

I'm trying to set up a contact form for a client who wish to link the data from the form into their Goldmine system.

There is a 3rd party company who have sent me a sample contact form and a sample PHPMailer script, but when I test this script on the client's website it sends out the email, but as an attachment rather than in the body of the email.

I've looked at the PHPMailer script and I cannot see anywhere that references adding attachments so I'm puzzled as to whether there is something in the PHPMailer script I've not seen, or if this is some sort of server setting when the email is being sent? Any help would be appreciated.

The PHPMailer script has $Body which it just keeps adding each part of the form input to and then finally ends with what looks like the relevant bit of code to send the email:

```
ini_set("SMTP", Decode($SMTP));
if(mail(Decode($SendToEmail), $ToSubject, $Body, "From: GoldMine WebImport <no-reply@xxxxxxx>\r\nContent-Type: text/x-gm-impdata\r\n" )) {
print "Your data has been recorded successfully!\n\n<!--\n".Decode($SendToEmail)."\n".$ToSubject."\n".$Body."\n\n".$OutputAs."\n\n-->";
}
    else
    {print("There was a mailer failure.\n\n<!--\n".$Body."\n\n-->");}
}
else
{echo "There was no form data passed.";}
```

EDIT: I should also mention that I've been using Tectite's Formmail system for the same client on their existing contact forms and that sends the email with the content in the main body of the email as it is supposed to. I only seem to be having this problem with PHPMailer, but I can't use Formmail for sending the right info to the Goldmine system.

Comment: PHPMailer ≠ the PHP `mail()` function. Since you've tagged this as a PHPMailer question, how about [using it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)? The example in the readme should be enough to get you going.

Comment: I don't use PHPMailer, I was sent a PHP file called PHPMailer from the 3rd party dealing with Goldmine with the script inside it to take in the information from the web form, format it and then send it in an email.

If this isn't actually PHPMailer then thanks for letting me know it isn't so I'm not wasting your or my time in going down this route.